# Is ADSL digital or analog?

Tags: networking, signals, communication, modulation, adsl

I've read that ADSL uses frequency-divided multiplexing and only analog signals use FDM. Then why there's the term 'digital' in ADSL(Asymmetric digital subscriber line) if it uses analog signals?

Comment: The "D" in any xDSL variant stands for "Digital." ADSL is Asymmetric _Digital_ Subscriber Line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal is digital, the line encoding that implements this signal is described in the real macro world with analog.

Comment: Does signal travel through transmission media as an analog signal?

Comment: Yes, in layman's terms.  it's a combo of phase, frequency, and amplitude modulation/"shift-keying", aka "QAM".

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to imagine it, digital signal is broken into different frequencies like a piano keys.

Then each tone is sent down the copper wire like a sound, this is then picked up at the far end and then Demodulated back into a digital string of 1s a nd 0s.

A modems name is created from the job it does as a Modulator / Demodulator.